# How to Display Popup Menu in Near Position on BarChart Item Click?

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, popupmenu

How to Display Popup Menu in Near Position on BarChart Item Click ?

I have created a app to to show popup menu on Bar chart item click. The Problem is the popup menu is not showing near to the bar chart item clicked. it always shows on top . So help me out to show popup menu near to bar chart item click .

Main activity:

```
package com.example.saravanakumars.spinnerchart;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] chart = {"Select", "Bar Chart", "Pie Chart"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, chart);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(aa);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2, long arg3) {

                String items = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                switch (items) {
                    case "Select":
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Select Bar or Pie Chart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case "Bar Chart":
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, barchart.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case "Pie Chart":
                        Intent p = new Intent(MainActivity.this, piechart.class);
                        startActivity(p);
                        break;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Barchart.java

```
package com.example.saravanakumars.spinnerchart;

/**
 * Created by saravanakumars on 9/18/2017.
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.OnChartValueSelectedListener;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class barchart extends AppCompatActivity {
    BarChart chart ;
    ArrayList<BarEntry> BARENTRY ;
    ArrayList<String> BarEntryLabels ;
    BarDataSet Bardataset ;
    BarData BARDATA ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bar_chart);
        chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);

        BARENTRY = new ArrayList<>();

        BarEntryLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

        AddValuesToBARENTRY();

        AddValuesToBarEntryLabels();

        Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY, "Projects");

        BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels, Bardataset);

        Bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        chart.setData(BARDATA);

        chart.animateY(3000);
//        chart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(barchart.this,chart);
//
//                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
//                popup.show();
//
//                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
//                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
//                        Toast.makeText(barchart.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        return true;
//                    }
//                });
//            }
//        });
        chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener( new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {

                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(barchart.this,chart);

                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
                popup.show();

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(barchart.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {

            }
        });


    }

    public void AddValuesToBARENTRY(){

        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(2f, 0));
        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(4f, 1));
        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(8f, 3));
        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(7f, 4));
        BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(3f, 5));

    }

    public void AddValuesToBarEntryLabels(){

        BarEntryLabels.add("January");
        BarEntryLabels.add("February");
        BarEntryLabels.add("March");
        BarEntryLabels.add("April");
        BarEntryLabels.add("May");
        BarEntryLabels.add("June");

    }



}
```

popup menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:title="Type-1"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:title="Type-2"/>
</menu>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try MarkerView available in MPAndroidChart. [Check this link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView). I think It will help you to get the work done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the content view in a popup window at the specified location. You should use `showAtLocation(View view, int gravity, int x, int y)` method instead of `show()` method.

see more about showAtLocation method here [showAtLocation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int))